mocks are not getting cleared between each test scenario
I have a vitest test suite in vue 3, which calls a repo as an http wrapper, which I plan on mocking its return values into 1, 2, 3 for each test, and the vue component should call the appropriate endpoint with router.replace depending on the returned response value.
The problem is, when I create multiple test scenarios under the same describe block, the last value sticks, and gets persisted into all other test scenarios. For example, below I have 3 test scenarios. The third one will succeed, and the first two will fail because the first two receives a mocked value of 3, instead of 1 or 2.
The console.log() shows that all tests executed with a response of 3. The test succeeds if there's only one (when I comment out any other two scenarios)
I have been using clearAllMocks(), and resetAllMocks() in both the beforeEach, and afterEach blocks, but none are working.
describe('redirect page according to appStatus', () => {
    let wrapper
    let routerReplaceSpy
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const pinia = createPinia()
        setActivePinia(pinia)
        router = createRouter({
            history: createWebHistory(),
            routes: routes
        })
        store = useMyStore()

        routerReplaceSpy.push('/home')
        await router.isReady()
        routerReplaceSpy = vi.spyOn(router, 'replace')
        vi.clearAllMocks()
    })

    test('when res = 1', async () => {
        vi.mock('@/utils/repo', async() => ({
            post: vi.fn((path, data) => {
                const res = {}
                res = '1'
                console.log(res)
                return Promise.resolve(res)
            })
        }))
        wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            global: {
                plugins: [router]
            }
        })
        await flushPromises()
        expect(routerReplaceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            name: 'page1',
            id: '0001'
        })
    })

    test('when res = 2', async () => {
        vi.mock('@/utils/repo', async() => ({
            post: vi.fn((path, data) => {
                const res = {}
                res = '2'
                console.log(res)
                return Promise.resolve(res)
            })
        }))
        wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            global: {
                plugins: [router]
            }
        })
        await flushPromises()
        expect(routerReplaceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            name: 'page2',
            id: '0002'
        })
    })

    test('when res = 3', async () => {
        vi.mock('@/utils/repo', async() => ({
            post: vi.fn((path, data) => {
                const res = {}
                res = '3'
                console.log(res)
                return Promise.resolve(res)
            })
        }))
        wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            global: {
                plugins: [router]
            }
        })
        await flushPromises()
        expect(routerReplaceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            name: 'page3',
            id: '0003'
        })
    })

})


You can't use vi.mock inside a test like that, you need to be aware what it really does https://vitest.dev/api/vi#mock-modules . It can't change the implementation of already imported module by magic. You need to call vi.mock once at the top of the module and change the implementation of "post" spy per test
